# Iterate with streams (with a flag in for) [keep state within lambda]

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I have two lists, allowedOU and parts. I need to know how to iterate through streams, check the condition and if it is true, include the element in a third list, and change the flag (heritable).

```java
for (String part : parts) {
    for (BeanOU it : allowedOU) {
        if (part.startsWith("OU") && it.OU.equals(part.substring(3) && heritableFlag) {
            list.add(part.substring(3, part.length()));
            heritableFlag = it.heritable;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried something like this

```
parts.stream()
        .filter(parte -> allowedOU.stream()
                .anyMatch(allowed -> (parte.startsWith("OU")) 
                        && allowed.OU.equals(parte.substring(3, parte.length())) 
                 && finalHeritableFlag))
        .forEach(here we don't have it variable...)
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason to use streams for this? Just because you can use streams doesn't mean it is the right tool for the job everywhere.

Comment: As @MarkRotteveel has already pointed out, streams are not the right tool for everything. The way you're trying to utilize stream is discouraged by the [*API documentation*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#SideEffects).

Comment: And even your imperative code looks a bit fishy. Do you really want this line to be executed multiple times `heritableFlag = it.heritable;` ? Would it be the correct behavior when the flag changes multiple times?

Comment: ok, maybe I have tried hard enough to go down that path, not being the recommended one. thanks for your feedback :-)

Comment: yes, once it enters and it's false I don't want it to enter again. It could be done in a better way. Even so, the remaining iterations do nothing, it would be inefficient to keep going through the loop. Thank you very much :) @AlexanderIvanchenko

Answer (score 0):

"The results of the flow pipeline can be non-deterministic or incorrect if the behavior parameters of the flow operations are stateful."

"Most stream operations accept parameters that describe user-specified behavior, which are often lambda expressions. To preserve correct behavior, these behavior parameters should not interfere, and in most cases should be stateless. Such parameters are always instances of a functional interface such as Function, and are often lambda expressions or method references".

I leave this in case someone needs it!

an approximation to stop when a certain condition is met, it offers us is **takeWhile**

```
 List<String> partsList = Arrays.asList(parts);
        partsList = partsList.stream().filter((a->a.startsWith("OU"))).map(s->s.substring(3)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<String> finalPartsList1 = partsList;
        listOUallowedByUser = allowedOU.stream().takeWhile(allowed -> allowed.heritable).filter(f-> finalPartsList1.contains(f.OU)).map(a-> a.OU).collect(Collectors.toList());;
```

thanks for mark-rotteveel and alexander-ivanchenko :-)

Answer (score 0):

I am using stateful Map iterator like the below supporting two states, easily extendable to support more state, just change to Iterable if you need for List instead of Map.  State is a simple class with one instance variable. (I am sure there is a lib out there containing sth similar...)

```
public class StatefulMapIterator <K,V,T extends Map<K,V>, S1, S2> {
private State<S1> state1;
private State<S2> state2;

public interface Processor1<K,V,S1> {
    void onIteration(K key, V value, State<S1> state1);
}
public interface Processor2<K,V,S1,S2> {
    void onIteration(K key, V value, State<S1> state1, State<S2> state2);
}   
public StatefulMapIterator(S1 state) {
    this.state1 = new State<S1>(state);
}   
public StatefulMapIterator(S1 state1, S2 state2) {
    this.state1 = new State<S1>(state1);
    this.state2 = new State<S2>(state2);
}
    
public void foreach(T t, Processor1<K,V,S1> processor) {
    t.forEach((k,v) -> {
        processor.onIteration(k,v, state1);
    });
}
public void foreach(T t, Processor2<K,V,S1,S2> processor) {
    t.forEach((k,v) -> {
        processor.onIteration(k,v, state1, state2);
    });
}
}
```